# Android - layout is defined in two seperate files?

Tags: android, xml, layout, styles

I found out that the layout of my activity is defined in two files. This is my main.xml in /res/menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- The main content view -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            style="@style/NavigationDrawer"/>

            <!--  android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#111"/> -->

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


    <item
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        android:title="@string/add_button"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

And here you can find my activity_main.xml in the /res/layout/ subfolder.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">


    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        style="@style/NavigationDrawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

As you can see, e.g. the navigation drawer is defined twice. Is that necessary? And do I have to write every change into both files?

Comment: Can't you re-use layout containing Drawer Layout using <include>?

See - http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below from main.xml. No need have to make any changes in main.xml if you make changes in your layout file.

Check the below link for layouts.`activity_main.xml` is a layout file

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

`main.xml` is a menu resource

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- The main content view -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            style="@style/NavigationDrawer"/>

            <!--  android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#111"/> -->

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Well, that seems logical. Don't know how I could add all this to a menu resource.

Comment: @user2971688 you need not add all those to menu resource. check the links in mypost